# CRUD table/card view best practice?

Tags: usability, gui-design, design-patterns, experience

What is the best view for CRUD? Is it table or card view?

CRUD structure is
Name: XYZ
Date: dd/mm/yy
Query: location: a1,a2; State: s1,s2;etc

In my CRUD only editable field is Name. I can edit and update name. In addition to this there will be alert frequency (i.e whether i would like to receive it weekly, monthly or quarterly) in which user can select among multiple views and select the one which user is interested in.

I feel card view works out because my query can be very long. So I can give an option read more/less. Table view will look odd as some view's will long and some short.

Comment: I think "CRUD" has nothing to do with your situation and just confuses readers of this question.  You need to let us know... how many of these do you need to display at once? 1, 2,3, 100s? What is the max length of the query property? What is the use case for this? Will the user instinctively know what the query is all about?

Comment: It can be any number. There will be lazy loading for this with search. Query length can be long. I can choose any country, city, state, category, amount etc. It's similar to bookmark that we have in google chrome. Instead of user retyping the same query again. User can choose among  the list. Yes, user will know what query is all about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact or correct answer the way you have asked the question, but here are some different contexts that will help to come up with a suitable solution:

- Mobile vs. desktop views
- Complexity of the Query result returned
- Number of entries per view (average)
- Type of platform (Windows/Mac/Android)